# Dynamic jolt to handle when single array or multiple arrays are sent in a single message

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

Dynamic Jolt spec to handle when one array is present and and multiple arrays not present

My jolt spec is working perfectly fine if we receive one array, but if they send a JSON multiple arrays its failing.

Input 1

```
[
    {
    "Name": "Thiyagarajan1columntest"
    },
    {
    "Name": "Thiyagarajan1columntest2"    
    }
]
```

Input 2

```
[
    {
    "Name": "Thiyagarajan1columntest1"
    },
    {
    "Name": "Thiyagarajan1columntest2"    
    }
]
[
    {
    "Name": "Thiyagarajan1columntest3"
    },
    {
    "Name": "Thiyagarajan1columntest4"    
    }
]
[   {
    "Name": "Thiyagarajan1columntest5"
    },
    {
    "Name": "Thiyagarajan1columntest6"    
    }
]
```

Output Needed

```
[
    {
    "Name": "Thiyagarajan1columntest1"
    },
    {
    "Name": "Thiyagarajan1columntest2"    
    }
]
,
    {
    "Name": "Thiyagarajan1columntest3"
    },
    {
    "Name": "Thiyagarajan1columntest4"    
    }
,
  {
    "Name": "Thiyagarajan1columntest5"
    },
    {
    "Name": "Thiyagarajan1columntest6"    
    }
]
```

Comment: Hi Thiyagaraj. The second input and the expected output are not valid JSON values while The Jolt is library which converts from JSON to JSON. Btw, can you please share your current spec tried.